# repeating statement in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a function that can be used to repeat the statement in excel macro.
The case is like this :

- I have some statement in my macro like this :

  ```
   alline = alline & "Department Section" & Chr(10)
   alline = alline & "sectorNumber=" & """" & "1" & """" & Chr(10)
   alline = alline & Chr(10)

   alline = alline & "<Sector" & Chr(10)
   alline = alline & "sectorNumber=" & """" & "2" & """" & Chr(10)
   alline = alline & Chr(10)

   alline = alline & "<Sector" & Chr(10)
   alline = alline & "sectorNumber=" & """" & "3" & """" & Chr(10)
   alline = alline & Chr(10)
  ```
- If I using this command, my excel macro procedure will be too large and can not compile.
- Is it possible for me to simplify my command so I can reduce memory to be compiled by macro?

Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Have you considered looping?

Comment: @L42 sorry for late response. how to use looping for this situation? i am confused to use loop.

Comment: Well based on your sample the only thing that changes is the sector number except for the first instance of the Department Section which can be handled by an IF statement. Btw, how many sector number are we talking about here. Also, the purpose is to concatenate all sector in `alline` variable? Is that correct?

Comment: @L42 I want to make 8 sector number. Sorry i have mistaken in the first. It supposed to be "<sector" too. I want to make the output extension in XML. So that I expect to write all sector (1-8) without wasting memory (because when I wrote for 8 sector, the macro can't compile due to limit memory). Please kindly help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do some actions for many times you need to use `loop` statements:

> **For** statement (Most common loop statement):

Sample:

```
For i = 1 To 8
    'Your code here
Next i
```

Main:

```
For <counter variable> = <start number> to <end number> [step <step number>]
    'Codes
Next [<counter variable>]
'Default step number is 1
```

So you can use that like this:

```
For i =1 to 8
     alline = alline & "<Sector" & Chr(10)
     alline = alline & "sectorNumber=" & """" & CStr(i) & """" & Chr(10)
     alline = alline & Chr(10) 
Next i
```